# How do I access the linked table in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

My blog has multiple recipes in each blog post. And the recipes are used more than once across all blog posts.

I am trying to create a page where I can display all the recipes in a grid. Once the visitor clicks on a recipe I want it linked to the first blog post in the database that includes that specific recipe. Cause I have html pages for every blog post but not for every recipe.

I cannot wrap my head around how this will be structured and accomplished. Should I redesign the models or is there a way to do this with django templates? Any help will be appreciated!

`models.py`

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    

class PostRecipes(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Posts', models.DO_NOTHING)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipes', models.DO_NOTHING)


class Recipes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

`views.py`

```
def allrecipes(request):
    recipes = Recipes.objects.all()

    context = {
        'recipes': recipes,
    }
    return render(request, "All-recipes.html", context)
```

`All-recipes.html`

```
{% for item in recipes %}
  <a href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/{{ item.slug }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ManyToManyField` actually:

```py
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=155)
    

class Recipes(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    posts = mdoels.ManyToManyField("Posts", related_name='recipes')
```

Django docs example : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

After that, you can access related table via:

```py
Recipes.objects.first().posts # first recipe for example
Posts.objects.first().recipes # first post for example, accessing via related name
```

And in your template would be sth like this:

```
{% for item in recipes %}
  <a href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/{{ item.posts.first.slug }}">{{ item.posts.first.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Amin. Could you tell me how I would use that to render in django templates?

Comment: I've updated answer for you @haashe